# Tile fade problem with CATiledLayer

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm using an `UIScrollView` with `CATiledLayer`, with the default `fadeDuration` (no override).
When the tiled layer gets refreshed, apparently for some reason the last tile never fades in completely. I can actually see the tile with about 0.1 of transparency on the screen.
As soon as I scroll the scroll view even a little bit, the tile "refreshes" and it's all back to normal.

I've tested it on both the iPhone and iPad. Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Yes.  I'm setting fadeDuration to zero just to avoid the problem.  (iPad iOS 3.2)

Comment: @John Lemberger: I don't know how, but my app simply stopped doing it now. I'll let you know if I discover what happened.

Comment: I have the same problem.. and even setting the fadeDuration to zero won't fix fhe problem completely .. sometimes the last loaded tile fades in in a loop causing it to flicker ... without drawrect is called again

Comment: @Bastian it's weird that setting fadeDuration to zero won't fix it... How are you doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure why but my problem is gone now. Even with zero i saw the background through very fast flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself, probably with an SDK update.